# css styling and alignment issue

Tags: php, css, html

I would like my `<div id="container">` to be on the right side of my navigation menu but I am having issues.

Can anybody please help me out with this.

**index.php**

```
<!-- This is the page identifier. Change on each of your pages! -->
<?php $page ='page_index'; ?>
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Example of PHP include active navigation">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <header>
            <h1>Index page</h1>
        </header>

        <!-- This is where we want to include the nav.php file! -->
        <?php include("nav.php"); ?>

        <div id="main" role="main">
            <p>This is the index page</p>
        </div>

        <footer>
            <p>This is the footer</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**nav.php**

```
<nav role="navigation" id="<?php echo $page ?>">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="index" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="about" href="about.php">About</a></li>
        <li><a class="contact" href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>          
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**style.css**

```
nav ul {
    list-style: none; 
    display:inline-block;
        float:left;
}

ul a {
    color:green;

}

nav#page_index ul li a.index, 
nav#page_about ul li a.about, 
nav#page_contact ul li a.contact {
    color:red;
}
```

This is what I added to **style.css**

```
div.container
{
   float:left;
}
```

Please let me know how can I make left side navigation menu with some good looking formatting.

thanks in advance..!

Comment: according to your code you have to set width of `ul` and `container`

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the content you want beside the left navigation menu in a new `div` element.  Then add `float:left` to this container and the navigation menu. In a nutshell, you need to float both siblings to make them side by side.  Since there is not an apparent sibling, I suggesting making one by wrapping your content.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
        <header>
            <h1>Index page</h1>
        </header>

        <nav role="navigation" id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="index" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="about" href="about.php">About</a></li>
            <li><a class="contact" href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>          
         </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="main" role="main">
                <p>This is the index page</p>
            </div>

            <footer>
                <p>This is the footer</p>
            </footer>
         </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#content,#nav{
    float:left;
}
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/vmr95/

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not that clear. Inside the container menu code is written. I guess you mean div named **main**. If this is the case then you can add

```
#main{ float:left; }
```

and accordingly adjust the footer.